# Reading a float value from standard input and using in time.sleep

Tags: python, input

I'm currently struggling with simple code, it works with seconds but I want to allow users to use minutes instead, which is much easier. Here it is:

```
import time
import os
import math
import subprocess

input1 = raw_input("Broj minuta:")
min = input1 * 60
min1 = float(min)
print min1
time.sleep(min1)
os.system("shutdown")
```

I get this error:

```
Broj minuta:2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timer.py", line 8, in <module>
    time.sleep(min)
TypeError: a float is required
```

When I try to convert it to float using code below, it says that sleep time is big, and it is, if I choose 2 minutes I get:

```
min = input1 * 60
min1 = float(min)

Broj minuta:2
2.22222222222e+59
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "timer.py", line 10, in <module>
   time.sleep(min1)
OverflowError: sleep length is too large
```

Comment: It is not related to the reported problem, but generally I suggest avoid using 'min' as variable names since it is a built-in function for minimum.

Answer (score 4):

```
input1 = raw_input("Broj minuta:")
```

`raw_input` returns a string. You need to convert that to a number, like this

```
input1 = int(raw_input("Broj minuta:"))
```

If you don't do this, let say if you enter `2`, it will still be a string and you are doing

```
input * 60
```

which means `'2' * 60`, which is equal to `'222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222'` and it is still a string. That's why `time.sleep(min)` complains that

```
TypeError: a float is required
```

In the second case, you are converting `'222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222'` to a float properly, but the value is `2.22222222222e+59`, which is tooo big for `time.sleep`.

Answer (score 2):

(Your traceback must be out of date; it shows `time.sleep(min)` (in which case the error is justified), but your code has `time.sleep(min1)`.)

The issue is that the result of `raw_input` is a string. When you write `input1 * 60`, you repeat the string 60 times (i.e. instead of 120, you get `'222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222'`).

Answer (score 1):

You're performing the conversion too late. `input1` is a string, and multiplying a string by an integer

```
min = input1 * 60
```

does string repetition: `'12' * 60 == '12121212...`

Instead, convert to float, then multiply:

```
min = float(input1) * 60
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable returned by `raw_input` is a string.
To add more information to what is happening in your code, here is an example session.

```
In [1]: i = raw_input("Something")
Something20

In [2]: i
Out[2]: '20'

In [3]: type(i)
Out[3]: str

In [4]: i*60
Out[4]:     '202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020'

In [5]: float(i*20)
Out[5]: 2.02020202020202e+39
```

`Out [2]` shows the string `'20'`. This is confirmed when we check the type of `i`, which is `str`.
Now, in Python, when you multiply a string with a number `x`, you get a string with `x` times the original string repeated.

This is what was happening in your code. Thus, as suggested in the other answer, you need to cast your input to a float.

Another, way of doing this (on Python 2.x) is to NOT use `raw_input()` and instead use `input()`

```
In [6]: j = input('Something else?')
Something else?20

In [7]: j
Out[7]: 20

In [8]: j*60
Out[8]: 1200
```